# How to get a website's HTTP response headers with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers

I've been searching the entire day for this. All I want is to get **the http response headers** plus the **status code** for a given website using Node JS. That simple.

All the answers and documentation I checked seem far too hideously too complicated for this simple problem, plus I don't seem to be able to get them to work.

For example, one answer provided me with this code

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'google.com'
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

After trying it with google, the response code it shows me is 301, which is obvisouly just wrong

For that example, I believe the correct code would be "200" for OK. Plus this one doesnt show all the headers.

Comment: 301 is correct status code which means page was redirected. You are trying to hit `google.com` which then redirects to `https://google.com` thus the redirect

Comment: You should read about [HTTP Redirections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) first. And also, verify [here](https://httpstatus.io/) that the address `google.com` returns a 301 status code, then a 302 and finally a 200. That's how Google redirects users to their HTTPS protocol. Calling `google.com` is an HTTP protocol by default. Try calling: `https://www.google.com` directly to prevent redirections.

Comment: Calling google at https directly with that code gives me an error

Comment: @RaviMattar call `https://www.google.com` directly.

Comment: And how could I get all status codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that if I cURL `google.com` [I get a 301, redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)
[image]

This is because `google.com` is redirecting me to `www.google.com`.  However, if I cURL `www.google.com`, it gives me this response,

[image]

which is the webpage.  As far as the headers, they should be in `res.headers` according to the [https module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) which shows the following example

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

As you can see, they print the headers using `console.log('headers:', res.headers);`.  You can access a given header by using `res.headers['INSERT-HEADER-NAME-HERE']` where INSERT-HEADER-NAME-HERE is replaced with [the header that you want to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)

Comment: Gods, thank you so much! I finnaly got to understand a bit of this and managed to get it to work.